# Was T-X in some way responsible for Skynet's offensive actions on Judgement Day in T3?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

We know that T-X had some role in what happened on Judgement Day in T3.

It programmed some of military's robots to attack.

But was that 100% contained to dealing with localized situation of terminating John Connor?

In other words, did anything that T-X do increase the likelyhood that Skynet would decide to attack humans? (as opposed to decrease the likelyhood that humans would succeed in stopping the attack that was already decided on by AI).

I'm looking for **canonical evidence**, not guesses (e.g. movies, scripts, commentary, interviews, non-movie franchise works).

Comment: I'm looking for answers based in canon or franchise-related personnel. Doesn't have to be restricted to T3 canon or to movies.

Comment: What is T-X and T3? :P

Comment: @AndresF. - some characters from *Highlander 2* movie?

Comment: @DVK - You said in another question (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/how-did-skynet-screw-the-world-even-before-its-activation)  that my answer below did not satisfy you.  May I ask what is missing, or what you feel is incorrect?  I'd be happy to spend time and rework the answer using the movies again.

Comment: @TexasTubbs - there doesn't seem to be clear canon evidence in your answer for either equating TX's virus with "Skynet" computer virus; OR for treating them as separate things but assuming that TX's virus had any meaningful effect on resulting Skynet. You merely say "This could be coincidental, or it can be inferred that the corruption to SkyNet could very well have been caused by the virus". What I was looking for was canon evidence supporting or refuting one or both of those options.

Answer (score 3):

It's evident that as soon as SkyNet as created by Cyber Research Systems found the virus planted by TX, SkyNet became corrupted.  This could be coincidental, or it can be inferred that the corruption to SkyNet could very well have been caused by the virus.

SkyNet would come online eventually, with or without the virus planted by the TX.  The real question is, would a SkyNet which comes online much later evolve into a peaceful system, or realize that all people were the enemy?  If SkyNet would view all people as a threat no matter how it was developed and brought online, then what purpose was the virus supposed to serve?

In our court system, this would be called circumstantial evidence.  But if the shoe fits...

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. The virus already "infected half the civilian Internet as well as secondary military apps" at the time when the T-X arrived.