# How did Skynet screw the world even before its activation?

Tags: the-terminator, artificial-intelligence, the-terminator-series, skynet

In *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines* movie, Skynet infected most part of civilian Internet as a powerful unbeatable virus. It also broke US govt. firewall to hack US defense system. All these even before it was activated.

> **Robert Brewster:** Skynet? The virus has infected Skynet?
>   **John Connor**: ***Skynet IS the virus***. It's the reason everything's falling apart!
>   **Terminator:** Skynet has become self aware. In one hour it will initiate a massive nuclear attack on its enemy.

How can a software do such things even before its execution?

Comment: When the terminator woman with wireless abilities was sent back to the past, she had released a virus made by skynet from the future to force the release of skynet earlier. This virus was the skynet from the future which affected the “Skynet Defense System” in the past. Skynet from the future was the “Virus”, Skynet in the past was Skynet, which with the virus became self aware instantly. Why can’t I answer to this question?

Comment: @AnatolyWein This question seems to be protected, which means you can't answer it until you gain at least 10 reputations on this site itself, so says the yellow message.

Comment: @clockwork I have at least 100 reputation.

Comment: @AnatolyWein But not from this site.

Answer (score 28):

The question stems from an in-universe confusion. There are 3 things that exist in Terminator Universe, and 2 of them share a name:

1. A virus (which had nothing to do with the military) and had no name.
2. A military system/AI that General Brewster built, *called "Skynet" by its creators*.
3. A hostile self-aware AI running on military hardware, which was a result of the #1 virus infecting #2 AI/system.

   *That final self-aware AI was called "Skynet" by those who survived the Judgement Day.*

The problem is that most people - John Connor included, up till the very end of T3 movie - assumed that the resulting self-aware "Skynet" AI originated mainly due to the military AI (also called "Skynet" by the military).

That assumption was **wrong** - final Skynet was a result of an original virus software (which was infecting civilian Internet) infecting a military AI hardware. The infection happened **as the hardware was activated to try to play McAffee** and clean the virus out of the networks.

The conundrum that you expressed in your question (***"All these even before it was activated"***) was precisely due to that confusion: What was "activated later" was an AI/Hardware called "Skynet", but that was independent of Virus-that-evolved-into-Skynet.

Here's the actual timeline (precision up to 2 hours) based on the following quoted dialog in the T3 movie:

```
 T - X years:  General Brewster develops an autonomous military system
               combining drones and a powerful AI codenamed "Skynet".

 T - 10 days:  An unnamed virus activates (for arbitrary values of "10").
               The virus was/is completely unrelated to Brewster's "Skynet"

 T - 2 hours:  Virus infects some DoD military systems. 

 T - 1 hour:   DoD freaks out and orders General Brewster to turn on
               his Skynet AI to clean military networks from the virus.

 T - 59 mins:  Skynet AI gets infected by the virus.
               Combined infected software achieves self-awareness.
               This combined software will be dubbed "Skynet" afterwards.

 T - 0 mins:   "Bad" Skynet launches Judgement Day.
```

---

> **Robert Brewster:** Skynet? The virus has infected Skynet?
>   **John Connor**: ***Skynet IS the virus***. It's the reason everything's falling apart!
>   **Terminator:** Skynet has become self aware. In one hour it will initiate a massive nuclear attack on its enemy.
>
> **John Connor:** By the time Skynet became self-aware it had spread into millions of computer servers across the planet. Ordinary computers in office buildings, dorm rooms; everywhere. ***It was software; in cyberspace. There was no system core; it could not be shutdown.***

Comment: Skynet was only Software. It was quoted by John Connor in the end.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - yes, I included that quote :)

Comment: Which is interesting because shouldn't it have gotten progressively dumber as the nuclear war wiped out most of the systems it was running on?

Comment: The virus which infected the internet was brought back by the Terminatrix, wasn't it? She certainly infects civilian systems with a virus during the film.

Comment: @Nick No. She infects isolated machines, none of them connected to the internet (e.g. trucks etc...). Her nanovirus thingies are a tool of Terminatoring, not of creating Skynet

Comment: @DVK I'm pretty sure I got the impression she infected the internet via a mobile phone as one of the first things she did. Its been a while since I saw the film though!

Comment: Looked at the script, she used a cellphone to hack into the FBI computers to find John Conner. Seems most likely she left the virus at the same time?

Comment: Can you provide canonical reference which says that Katherine's father merely activated a hardware? AFAIK, Katherine's father activated Skynet program to clear virus and he didn't know that `Skynet was the virus`. Well, my question: How could that virus (skynet) do something before its activation?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - you are simply confusing 2 things. The **virus** - which was in reality what Skynet was - was ALREADY active. The military AI - which was called "Skynet" - was activated to clean the virus. Later on in history, because people didn't realize or care about fine details, they merely called the resulting abomination of an AI infected with the virus "Skynet", the same way people refer to "Linux OS" instead of "GNU/Linux" (GNU operating system running Linux kernel)

Comment: @DVK :) Nice theory. Again, I'd ask for canonical reference. Or, there'd be another question: How did "Virus Skynet" come in existence?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - canonical reference is in the 2 quotes I listed. And yes, it doesn't answer 'How did "Virus Skynet" come in existence' because that's a completely separate question you did NOT ask.

Comment: Mind it, it was (US govt.'s) Skynet which was successor of AI research project of Cyberdyne Systems.

Comment: No. I am asking reference for TWO Skynets.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - the first Skynet reference is in the first quote: Brewster says: "The virus has infected Skynet?" - he was talking about his baby AI. The second Skynet reference is an entire T1 and T2 movies where the resulting AI was called "Skynet" by everyone and their mother.

Comment: @Nick -  T-X infection was already discussed on SFF.SE - my own question, as it happened. Nobody answered to my satisfaction :(  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21601/was-t-x-in-some-way-responsible-for-skynets-offensive-actions-on-judgement-day

Comment: Brewster merely asked a question while dying. He wasn't giving information. So, it can't be counted as reference.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - he **called** the system "Skynet". Without knowing anything about Judgement Day/future.

Comment: 1. Unable to understand your last comment. 2. If virus was able to beat military's AI skynet, it means that virus was also AI and was real origin of ultimate Skynet. Then, T-850 would have told about creator of virus.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - you (and intelligent human being) can be easily killed by a bunch of absolutely dumb pathogens, from plague to Ebola to flu to fles-eating bacteria. Never mind rats/snakes/sharks/lions. Your last statement is absolutely wrong as far as the virus needing to be an AI

Comment: @DVK :D your logic is wrong. See the dimensions of both. Both can only fight with algorithms. One can't simply un-plug the power cable.

Comment: @Xantac, I read a network/percolation paper at uni once and you need to wipe out nearly every PC (>99.9% ) to destroy the internet. Or something.

Comment: @Pureferret Mostly correct.  There's a handful of [key internet hubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/60_Hudson_Street) in the world that, if outright destroyed, would cripple the interconnectivity of the internet.  IIRC, the "internet" would still work as a bunch of networks mostly separated from each other, having to go through other hubs instead of the destroyed one.

Comment: @SachinShekhar As for the virus, it doesn't have to be an AI itself.  It could just be targeted in a way that corrupted a few key subroutines in the AI.  That's the fun of automatic code generation:  The tiniest change can cascade all over as it attempts to correct itself and keep going.

Comment: @Izkata Don't forget the subroutine was AI powered specially designed against virus.

Comment: @SachinShekhar- plenty of computer viruses today have code aimed at subverting known antiviruses, or even unknown ones.

Comment: This can't be compared with that. Today's virus & anti-virus are programmed to do finite no. of actions. An AI-powered anti-virus can learn everything about virus & attack with an non-listed move to which normal virus can't stand chance.

Comment: I didn't read it this way. My reading of the timeline was; Skynet created but largely contained. Skynet releases virus onto internet, military release skynet's controls and allow him to upload fully into military systems, skynet burns the world.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I'm reasonably certain that Skynet had escaped the box and put a virus onto the commercial Internet.

Comment: Cyberdyne execs created the virus out of spite.......................

Comment: your answer says that the virus infected skynet, but that is exactly what the dialogue disproves: "Q: The virus has infected Skynet? A: Skynet IS the virus". the virus didn't infect skynet, because skynet is the virus.

Answer (score 10):

I don't agree that the virus is independent of Skynet. Lets start with the only quote we have:

> Robert Brewster:
>   Skynet? The virus has infected Skynet?
>
> John Connor:
>   **Skynet is the virus**. It's the reason everything's falling apart.
>
> Terminator:
>   **Skynet has become self aware**. In one hour it will initiate a massive nuclear attack on its enemy.

and at the end

> John Connor: **By the time Skynet became self-aware it had spread into millions of computer servers across the planet**. Ordinary computers in office buildings, dorm rooms; everywhere. It was software; in cyberspace. There was no system core; it could not be shutdown.

This can be interpreted 2 ways the first is in DVKs answer, the other is that Skynet created the virus so that its would be given access to systems it couldn't yet control (because its 'hands are tied').

Here is the sequence of events as I interpret it:

- The military creates a powerful AI, during its testing they run simulations. (Skynet spends its time runs through lots and lots of tactical simulations). But at this point is not self aware.
- One (or many) of these tactical simulations result in the best action to take being to strike first. (Tactically, the side that strikes first has the advantage. So most of these 'war games' would result in a 'strike first' outcome). At this point were talking about attack on foreign governments not humanity.
- Skynet can't see a way to win if its controllers (humans) wont acts, so it creates a virus, that is strong enough that humans are unlikely to beat it alone.
- The military 'frees Skynets hands' to fight the virus.
- Skynet now takes control of every computer on the planet, (a massive boost to its processing power), It now has the computational power to become a 'true AI' (self aware). It becomes self aware on the central core its running on and the internet becomes extra 'neurons'.
- Skynet now a 'true AI' decides humans are a real threat to its survival and decides to wipe out humanity. (note that it takes 1 hour to launch the missiles, it has to become self aware first, then see humans as a threat).

In conclusion: Skynet was being run by the military anyway to test its abilities, and help it learn. It makes no sense to turn off an AI - better to let it learn (usually). The quotes mentioned could easily be interpreted this way too. When it spread to every computer it couldn't be shut off at the Core, as it would still exist online.

So to answer the question. Skynet was running to test its abilities and learn, but only had limited outside access. It was enough for it to spread the virus and wait until the humans gave it total control.

Comment: I agree with this. The failure on the part of General Brewster was to give Skynet access to the military mainframes. It already had access to the commercial internet but couldn't really do much with that other than create an almighty nuisance.

Answer (score 8):

The implication was that as the timestream fluctuated, in this particular instance of it Skynet was no longer created by the US military.

Instead, it was some emergent phenomenon of the Internet. It was born there uncreated, and only then did it infiltrate SIPRnet and the weapons prototypes. This confuses Connor because he'd been taught his whole life that it was a creation of weapons scientists as indeed it had been in the previous instance of the timestream. It is possible that this fluctuation wasn't persistent, and that one more iteration of the loop would cause it to swing back to a more familiar story.

It's actually quite unusual, I can only think of a handful of science fiction stories that depict emergent intelligence like this. Almost all go with the "artificially created" variety.

Comment: Nice answer.. but, I don't see anything from canon.

Comment: Um...[Jane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_(Ender's_Game))?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Well, I didn't happen to be watching it at the very moment that you posted the question. It's in there though.

Comment: @DVK Jane was actually some sort of spacemormon-soul called by aliens or some crap like that. Does it count?

Comment: @JohnO - Jane was explained pretty comprehensively on SFF.SE. It was a combination of a very powerful AI merged with a "soul" (aka philote).

Comment: [Digimon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon) are all emergent intelligences  =)

Comment: @Izkata - are those in any way related to Pokemon?

Comment: @DVK **headbang** Noooooooo.....

Answer (score -1):

The only plausible explanation is that John Connor was wrong when he said "Skynet is the virus!" Skynet was a complex program that had the ability to learn (much like Joshua in War Games). It became self aware after is was turned on and uploaded to the vast network of military computers and gained access to all the processing power of the entire network- which it did quite quickly, and decided that the real threat was the human race. In reality the problem is the writers for Terminator 3 didn't care that their story was flawed. When John Connor said "Skynet is the Virus!" the wrtiters intended for it to be true and wanted the viewers to believe it. This statement creates a flaw in the story. I am sure someone noticed it but expected the audience would be wowed by all the action and not notice and/or not care.

Comment: welcome to stack exchange.. a good answer should have fact to support what you think. "i am sure" is not really credible. Where do you take your facts about these sayings ?

Comment: So you are saying the writers didn't notice it? Fine. There is still a major flaw. Skynet can not create a virus before it was self aware. The only way to make the story work is for John Connor to be wrong and the virus created by some unknown 3rd party source.

Answer (score -2):

No, Skynet is not a virus. It's just the military net control system. It became "self-aware" (made up his own mind and purpose). It was active all the time, it was just "activated", as in self-checking and repairing errors. They just didn't think it would turn against its designers. In other words, because of lack of resources, they were playing with fire when they gave machines full freedom to decide what to do. They made it self-aware, and they blew it on themselves.

Comment: Skynet was virus. See the quote in DVK's answer.