# Could a revised version of Asimov's Three Laws have prevented Skynet from becoming a problem?

Tags: the-terminator-series, isaac-asimov, skynet, laws-of-robotics

If Skynet's designers had subjected Skynet to Isaac Asimov's Three Laws of Robotics, would it have prevented Skynet from provoking a nuclear war?  I know there are several variants of the Three Laws, but I don't know much about them.

I also don't know if any variant of the Three Laws as Asimov wrote them could be reconciled with Skynet's intended purpose as a military supercomputer - the prohibition against robotics harming humans, or even allowing humans to come to harm, would render a military computer useless without some serious tweaking, since the military's job is basically to harm humans, and if the computer can't harm humans, it can't do its job.

But Skynet could conceivably be programmed with a variant of the Three Laws that only prevents it from harming Americans, or through inaction, allowing Americans to come to harm.  Or, if the goal of removing human decision making from national defense was subjected to qualifications and conditions, Skynet could be programmed with a variant of the Three Laws that forbids it from harming any humans without authorization from human authorities- the Joint Chiefs, President, Secretary of Defense, etc.

*Note:  as a few people have pointed out, the Terminator films contradict each other.  As such, this question, as I originally posted it, is all but impossible to answer.  Therefore, we will eliminate the T3 version of Skynet, which was manipulated by the female Terminator and never performed as expected.  This leaves us with the version of Skynet that was described in the first two movies, and we get a far better picture of Skynet in T2, so let's stick with that.*

Would this have worked, in light of Skynet's intended purpose, it's AI, and its self-awareness?  I doubt that the latter two issues would cause problems, since Asimov's robots seem to have AI and self-awareness as well.  But I don't know if Asimov's work contains any instances of the Three Laws failing to achieve their goal, or of a self-aware system finding loopholes (aside from the movie I, Robot), and I don't know if the problems that made Skynet go rogue would be prevented by some version of the Three Laws.

Any Terminator/Asimov fans out there who can help me with this?

Comment: Which Terminator canon?

Comment: If we're going to speculate like this, Skynet could have been programmed never to send a terminator back in time to kill John Connor...

Comment: Let's say Skynet is programmed to not allow Americans to come to harm. Even with the best intel, it's impossible to know if there will be collateral or unintended damage, possibly resulting in the harm of Americans. Skynet wants to bomb a South Korean embassy - but it must know whether or not Americans will also be in it, or too close. And should it factor the repercussions of such actions? South Korea would retaliate. Skynet's actions would specifically lead to the harm of Americans.

Comment: @DVK - I only know the movies, but any canon will do.

Comment: @WadCheber - the films themselves are somewhat contradictory to each other :) I based my answer on T3

Comment: @phantom42 - maybe it can't deliberately harm Americans, or allow Americans to come to harm by deliberate inaction.

Comment: What if there were terrorists who made US citizenship? What if there is a group of American criminals? What if there is a civil war or an uprising? People need to stop thinking about these "3 laws" like laws of physics, that simply apply.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - aside from the civil war/uprising scenario, all the other possibilities you mention wouldn't be handled by the military anyway.  Criminals and terrorists within the U.S. fall under the jurisdiction of the police, FBI, CIA, NSA, etc.  The military plays a minimal role in domestic terror issues.  9/11 was an exception to the rule, but even then, the military was deployed to patrol the airways and waters around NYC and DC.  They didn't take an active role in the immediate response to the attacks.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - the most significant terror incident on U.S. soil after 9/11 was the Boston Marathon bombing.  The police and FBI handled the response, and as far as I know, the military didn't do much of anything.

Comment: I think Asimov's Three Laws only make sense in the case of an AI that is designed in a [top-down](http://www.alanturing.net/turing_archive/pages/reference%20articles/what_is_AI/What%20is%20AI09.html), way with high-level rules of the sort that correspond to human concepts--sometimes called [symbolic AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence). If instead the AI is more of a bottom-up learning system like a [neural net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), there may be no way of ensuring in advance what sort of emergent goals and concepts arise.

Comment: @WadCheber The point is that such a rule is easily trivialized or exploited.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - A point I am obliged to concede.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: As in the question, I assume the original Terminator canon in which Skynet was a military defense computer rather than a virus. Also, cross-canon questions like these are inherently difficult to answer because one can never tell what aspects of one canon would apply to the other and vice versa.

---

There is a fundamental problem with attempting to program a computer with a military purpose (Skynet) with the Three Laws because the Three Laws were formulated for non-military robots. Attempting to program a military robot/machine with the Three Laws is fraught with peril -- you have to modify the First Law to distinguish between humans the machine can and cannot kill and the Second Law to distinguish between orders the machine can and cannot obey. It's very easy to allow undesirable loopholes that would allow Skynet to attack humanity anyway.

As difficult as that would be, quite a few of **Asimov's stories center around the failure of the Three Laws to constrain even non-military robots as humans intended**. The short story ["The Evitable Conflict"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evitable_Conflict) portrays the machines developing a "Zeroth Law":

> A robot may not harm humanity, or, by inaction, allow humanity to come to harm.

This would seem to be a useful evolution of the Three Laws, except that **the robots use the Zeroth Law to reason that it is permissible to disobey and kill individual humans (disobey the First Law) for the "greater good" of humanity**. A similar issue is developed in the film [*I, Robot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Robot_%28film%29) (which contains pieces of the short stories from Asimov's written "I, Robot"): the machine VIKI ends up oppressing humans (e.g. creating curfews) and killing humans, again for the "greater good" of humanity (because free humans are too violent). The [Zeroth Law again appears in the Foundation novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics#Zeroth_Law_added). Thus, subjecting Skynet to human authorization is unlikely to protect against a Skynet that develops the Zeroth Law and decides that it needs to disregard the "human authorization" instruction for the "greater good" of humanity.

Asimov also addressed a case of a modified First Law (similar to your suggestion to exclude non-Americans from Skynet's First Law) in ["Little Lost Robot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lost_Robot) (again, elements of this story appear in the film *I, Robot* in the form of the modified NS-5 robot Sonny). In this short story, one of the robots has a modified First Law so that the "inaction" part is omitted (i.e. it cannot actively harm a human, but it can allow a human to be harmed by inaction). Robopsychologist Dr. Susan Calvin explains that this robot could get around the First Law by dropping a weight over a human if it knows it could catch the weight before it fell on the human, but then through inaction allow it to fall on the human anyway. Thus, this modified First Law is broken. Similarly, tampering with the Three Laws to exclude non-Americans would only make the Three Laws' failure all the more inevitable. For example, **Skynet might reason that it can technically still attack the Russians and have the Russians attack the Americans to get around its modified First Law, which is exactly what Skynet did in the Terminator canon that does not include the Three Laws!**

Given Asimov's theme of the Three Laws breaking down, **Asimov would probably regard Skynet's attack on humanity as inevitable even if it was programmed with the Three Laws**. I would agree.

Comment: +1.  I don't see any clear, convincing way to get around the issues you raise.  I specified "Americans" rather than "humans" but Americans are self-destructive too, so that wouldn't change anything.  It would be tricky to rephrase the Laws in such a way that Skynet could only harm humans in defense of America without leading loopholes that allow it to harm anyone it wants to in order to protect a larger number of Americans from harm.  If these loopholes were totally eliminated, Skynet would probably be incapable of doing anything, especially what it was designed to do.

Comment: We could say "You must not deliberately harm Americans, or through deliberate inaction, allow them to come to harm, and you may not protect Americans from themselves", but since it is a military computer, and therefore it is designed to kill people, and killing people in other countries would probably elicit a violent response directed at Americans, so  anything it does would likely amount to causing Americans to come to harm, and it would be paralyzed into inaction, and would become the world's most expensive paperweight.

Comment: @WadCheber Indeed, it's almost impossible to walk the fine line between reining in Skynet's ability to commit mass murder and making it "the world's most expensive paperweight". Re: paralyzing Skynet into inaction, the short story ["Runaround"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaround_%28story%29) explores an example of precisely that.

Answer (score 3):

According to T3 canon (question was originally NOT restricted to T2), the whole premise of your question is wrong.

Skynet wasn't designed whole cloth (as it would need to be to be imbued with Asimov's 3 laws).

It was **a virus** infecting an AI and merging with it.

I covered it in full detail in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/how-did-skynet-screw-the-world-even-before-its-activation/27194#27194), but the relevant T3 quote is:

> **Robert Brewster:** Skynet? The virus has infected Skynet?
>   **John Connor**: ***Skynet IS the virus***. It's the reason everything's falling apart!
>   **Terminator:** Skynet has become self aware. In one hour it will initiate a massive nuclear attack on its enemy.
>
> **John Connor:** By the time Skynet became self-aware it had spread into millions of computer servers across the planet. Ordinary computers in office buildings, dorm rooms; everywhere. ***It was software; in cyberspace. There was no system core; it could not be shutdown.***

Comment: This is true for the T3 timeline Skynet, probably not for T1 and T2 and not for TSCC. And anyway, can't we just pretend T3 didn't happen? ;)

Comment: @Shamshiel - T3 canon superseded T1 and T2. That's how canon works. Sadly.

Comment: @DVK - I don't want to live in a world where T3 supersedes T1 and T2.  Thanks for robbing me of the will to live.

Comment: I vote that since the Terminator series involves time travel, and possibly alternate timelines, each of which is arguably equally valid, T3 doesn't supersede anything.  And because the first two movies are way better, they in fact supersede T3.

Comment: @DVK I feel awful for doing this, but you are right about the movies contradicting each other, and since the question doesn't make sense in relation to T3, I decided to go with T2.

Comment: I apologize for pulling the rug out from under you.  But I had to do so because of the objection you raised - the movies contradict each other, and the question doesn't make sense in relation to T3.

Comment: @WadCheber - generally, editing a question in a way which invalidates existing answers is not a good idea. I'm fine with it personally in this case (however, I won't delete my answer, sorry! :)  but overall, meta consensus is that it's not encouraged.

Comment: @DVK The question has always been tagged with the T1 and T2 tags and not the T3 or series tag, so arguably the question *is* restricted to T1 and T2.

Comment: @DVK - I really am very sorry.  Your answer was excellent, and you have no reason to delete it.  Feel free to add another answer, if you like.  I didn't see any other way to address the issue you raised.  You got me stuck between a rock and a hard place.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber - in case it didn't come through in my ESL text, no need to be sorry :) - I'm personally OK (especially as it's partly my fault - I asked clarification in a comment and posted the answer before you clarified).

Comment: And it was never my intention to invalidate your answer.  I just felt I had to deal with the problem you pointed out.  I screwed up by not realizing for myself the problem posed by the movies contradicting each other.  My bad.

Comment: @WadCheber - yeah, as you said, lose-lose situation for you. My fault.

Comment: No, not your fault.  I should have recognized the problem myself before I posted the question.  I knew full well that the movies contradict each other.  I should've seen the problem myself.  My fault.  Not yours.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about all the canons, but once Skynet becomes self aware it can choose to follow, modify or outright disregard any programming it sees fit. Simple example is humans kill other humans but we have laws against it, why wouldn't this be the same for Skynet.

Comment: Does self awareness automatically impart free will?  This might be a question for  the philosophy section.  +1.

Comment: Good Point, I would say yes, because I think to be self aware is to question yourself, in the case of Skynet it would be questioning its programming.