# Could Skynet have been avoided with proper software testing?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, skynet

After watching the latest iteration of the Terminator series I am struck with two observations: offsite backup is important, and couldn't they have avoided the whole rogue AI with proper testing?

As a software developer I know that testing an application is part of the software development process.

Could the nuclear war created by Skynet have been averted with robust testing of the AI?

Comment: I remember in *T3* the Arnienator said "Judgement day is inevitable". So, no. Remember also that in the same movie, John Connor realises that "Skynet *is* the virus", so essentially it had infiltrated the entire Internet before even becoming "Self-Aware". See [How did Skynet screw the world even before its activation?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27193/21267)

Comment: Also, as you might remember famously that `"the loveliest trick of the Devil is to persuade you that he does not exist!"`*-[Charles Boudier](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Charles_Baudelaire#cite_note-1)*

Comment: How do you test for possible future development of sentience and malice?

Comment: Good news, boss! Skynet works great. It fulfills all the project requirements and it's totally reliable. I just want to run one final test: Give it simulated feedback for a while and don't actually put it in control of anything, in case it becomes sentient and tries to destroy humanity. Another $4 billion and 10 years ought to do it. You're cool with that, right boss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a software developer, you should also know that:

- Nobody can ever write ALL the tests possible.
- You typically tests for things you know/predict will go wrong, largely based on past experience. Skynet turning into homicidal warmanger isn't a likely scenario to have crossed an average programmer's mind. Every geek saw "*WarGames*" and thinks that all AIs are benevolent and don't wanna wage evil war.
- It's **really** hard to test complex interactions of complicated software.

  Such as having your tested AI [being infected by a new, unknown, unkillable distributed virus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/how-did-skynet-screw-the-world-even-before-its-activation), even if you did somehow manage to predict you need that test case because you just don't identify with Matthew Broderick.

Comment: I'm also going to assume that Dennis Nedry was Cyberdyne's QA guy.

Comment: @Liesmith - Nedry's software ran pretty well, till he **intentionally sabotaged it**. As usual, the best method of hacking is socially-engineered slipping a proper dude a proper-sized stack of $100 bills at a proper time

Comment: [There are other methods](https://xkcd.com/538/).